# Java, Reflection, and method invocation

Tags: java, reflection

I am having issue with reflection and calling only specific methods.
In my case I want to call the method getMyStuff() which may defined in more than one Class.

My classes look similar to this. MainClass will always be the parent.
I have a LOT of classes and not all the classes have the getMyStuff() method. I want to be able to call that method and access the return value. I have tried many incarnations of code to get access but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas,
Thanks

```
class MainClass
{
    public ClassA member1;
    public String getMyStuff() {}
}


class ClassA
{
    public ClassB member1;
    public String getMyStuff() {}
}


class ClassB
{
    public String getMyStuff() {}
}
```

Comment: And what is your issue here? Have you thought about using inheritance or creating an interface for `getMyStuff`?

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Is your reflection code not working? Do you have trouble understanding the concept?

Comment: create a better http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to explain your problem.

Comment: I have considered creating an interface but my classes number in the hundreds and they are auto-generated by jsonschema2pojo. These classes may have to change many times but the method getMyStuff() which is generated jsonschema2pojo should remain stable. So I wanted to pass the output of this method into another method for processing. Therefore I have about 1 place where code might need to be changed.  To Murat: My main issue is I understand the concept but do not know the mechanics on how to do this.

Comment: Can you write down what you have tried ?

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke the method using reflection like this:

```
public static String getMyStuff(Object o) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    Class<?> cl = o.getClass();
    Method m = cl.getMethod("getMyStuff");
    return (String) m.invoke(o);
}
```

However it would be far easier to add the method to an interface and implement this interface with the classes

```
public interface MyStuffContainer {
    public String getMyStuff();
}

class ClassA implements MyStuffContainer
{
    public ClassB member1;
    public String getMyStuff() {}
}

public static String getMyStuff(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof MyStuffContainer))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    return ((MyStuffContainer)o).getMyStuff();
}
```

---

The static `getMyStuff` method is called like this in both cases:

```
getMyStuff(new MainClass());
getMyStuff(new ClassA());
getMyStuff(new ClassB());
```

Comment: Good solution, not to mention that Reflection in java is rather slow!

Comment: I can see how the "public static String getMyStuff(Object o) " works and that is close to what I have. However I am unsure and have been unable to figure out how to iterate over the mainclass members and pass them as an object into that method. The interface, though a good idea, would be too unwieldy for this project.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you **extend** from MainClass and override getMyStuff() where needed?

Comment: Mine was not a new question. Since Reflection is slow in Java, I was suggesting to extend from MainClass. Also inheritance is good solution.

Comment: Sorry my bad, but anyway when you answer you should give a straight answer and not a question-like answer. Also this fits better as a comment rather as an answer....

Comment: I would have added a comment, but unfortunately I don't have 50 reputation points yet :)

Answer (score 0):

First go over your class and check if the class have the method you want:

```
Class c = ob.getClass();
for (Method method : c.getDeclaredMethods()) {
System.out.println(method.getName());
// check for the getMyStuff() method
}
```

if the method exist create an instance of that class and call the method:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class);
Object object = ctor.newInstance(new Object[] { ctorArgument });
```

Comment: I believe I have been successful with that when the getMyStuff() is in the MainClass. However once the method is attached to a member variable "member1" or inside of "ClassB" then I am not sure how to access it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it today. The main thing I had issue with was how to grab/access the objects in ClassA and ClassB. I was thinking you needed to iterate over the object somehow and access each object in turn. However Reflection has a different paradigm. You iterate over all the fields via getDeclaredFields(). Once you get a Field object for the field "Field field = aClass.getField("someField");" you then need to use the Field object to access the underlying object for that field "Object value = field.get(objectValue);"

I know this is not so good explanation but essentially I did not understand that you had to access the field first, pass in the object that the field is within, then "field.get(objectValue)" looks inside that objectValue and returns the object with that field name. Kinda reverse on how I think.

Thanks for the help.